# Failed to convert property value of 'java.util.Arraylist' to required type 'java.util.List'

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I am getting this error for the definition below.

```
<property name="configurationFiles">
   <list>
      <value>classpath:${common.dir}/abc.xml</value>
   </list>
</property>
```

Later on it goes to state that `abc.xml cannot be reolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system`.
What I am not getting is that the file is present and the `common.dir` also resolves to the correct directory name. What may be the issue?

Comment: Most likely it's hard to help you without seeing the exception itself. Moreover, if you supply a minimal program (all files) showing your problem - you have a better chance to get a hint here.

Comment: Another thing - but you might be seeing actually two problems not one. I am not sure what does file existence have to do with ArrayList to List cast, etc.